# TFS 2015 build Configuration

Tags: tfs-2015

I am trying to set up a TFS build server [on premise 2015]. The source is located on another server [TFS 2013]. While configurig build agent, an error occurs with below message.

Make sure you are using account server url 
(ex. https://account.visualstudio.com) not a collection server url (ex. https
://account.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection) to configure the agent.
API resource location a8c47e17-4d56-4a56-92bb-de7ea7dc65be is not registered on /tfs

Could anyone shed some light please.

Comment: Note: I have given account server url while configuring, not collection url as error message suggests.  http://tfsserver:port/tfs

Comment: Are you configuring a XMAL build agent or vNext build agent?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using `/ServerUrl:ServerUrl` during the configuration.

For troubleshooting configuration errors, detailed **logs** can be found in the `_diag` folder under the agent installation directory.

> Before you begin, make sure your build agent machine is set up with:
>
> **Requirements:**
>
> - An operating system that is supported by Visual Studio 2013 or newer
> - Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015
> - PowerShell 3 or newer (Where can I get a newer version of    PowerShell?)

Please also take a look at the detail steps for deploy and config build agent in this tutorial: [Deploy an agent on Windows for on-premises TFS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/agents/v1-windows#configure)

Also not suggest you to deploy the build agent on another TFS server.  Particularly, if there are 2013 build agents on the server. This may cause some confusion. Moreover, for TFS2015 it's agent based, doesn't have Controllers and you can install multiple agents on a single machine. Agents are grouped in Pools and live at the Server level, allowing you to use them across collections. There is no need to use physical machines economically.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Following is the error message on the log file                                                Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssResourceNotFoundException: API resource location a8c47e17-4d56-4a56-92bb-de7ea7dc65be is not registered on [tfs 2013 server url] at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<CreateRequestMessageAsync>d__69.MoveNext() End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown

Comment: It's not possible to use vNext build to build TFS 2013 repositories. The new builds are based on a different architecture and run on a completely different system.

Comment: You should move or  clone your code from TFS2013 to TFS2015.